# Bounds on expected absolute difference of ''logistic functions'' like random variable

Tags: probability, inequality, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions, bounded-variation

Let $p_1,\ldots,p_N,q_1,\ldots,q_N\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be fixed parameters, $X\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be a vector of $d$ independent normal random variables.

How can we show the existance of $L$ and some matrix norm $||\cdot||$ such that

$$
\mathbb{E}_X \sum_{i=1}^N\left|\frac{\exp(q_i^TX)}{\sum_{j=1}^N\exp(q_j^TX)} - \frac{\exp(p_i^TX)}{\sum_{j=1}^N\exp(p_j^TX)} \right| \le L \cdot ||\{q_1,\ldots,q_N\}-\{p_1,\ldots,p_N\}||.
$$

Comment: A natural way to try to start is to split the domain between $|X| \leq c$ and $|X|>c$. Do do a blunt bound on the contribution of the latter by exploiting the fact that it has relatively small probability. Do a more delicate Lipschitz constant-type analysis on the former. Then tune $c$ against $\| q-p \|$ to get the right scaling ($c$ will need to be a decreasing function of $\| q - p \|$, and will need to blow up as $\| q - p \| \to 0$).

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. Would you please elaborate a little bit on the Lipschitz constant-type analysis?

Comment: Basically you want to obtain a Lipschitz constant for $f(r;i,x)=\frac{\exp(r_i^T x)}{\sum_j \exp(r_j^T x)}$ as a function of $r$, which is uniform in $i$ and $x$, where $x$ is constrained to some fixed compact set.

Comment: Thanks again! This works intuitively when $d=1$ (i.e., $x\in\mathbb{R}$) and $N=2$.  I'm then a bit confused when the dimension goes up, say still $N=2$ but $d=2$. What will be the matrix norm then? @Ian